# How do I get user's language from the system or browser in a TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, tms-web-core

I'd like to know what language the user has set on his computer (system or browser).

How can I check or get the language with Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user's language with the `window.navigator.language` function from the `Web` unit.

Here's a function:

```
function GetSystemLanguage: String;
begin
  Result := window.navigator.language;
end;
```

---

Here's a list of results that can come from `window.navigator.language`: [List of ISO 639-1 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

Comment: The browser can have multiple languages set up - look it up in your own one's settings. As in: when the primary language is not available, use the secondary. Don't rely on **the** language (singular). On top: the browser's language(s) can differ drastically from the one in the OS **and** users might not even able to set them to their needs - someone working on a device not his own is then doomed to be bound to that setting and every website gives him a hard time by "_helping_" him. You're basically discovering what a browser has to offer - just learn JS/DOM.